# SAP Fiori Launchpad Custom App Error: Cannot instantiate object: "new" is missing

Tags: javascript, sapui5

After trying to start our custom developed SAPUI5 app in the fiori launchpad, we received following error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZAae.png)

**LPD_CUST Settings:**

[LPD_CUST_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stm1Z.png)

**Component.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
 ], function (UIComponent) {
  "use strict";
 return UIComponent.extend("***.***.***.Component", {
 metadata : {
   manifest: "json"
 },

init : function () {
  UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
 }
 });
});
```

**Target Mapping:**

[Target Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBjt.jpg)

**Semantic Object:**

Semantiv Object YCEI_BPUPLOAD_SEM exists in the Transaction /n/UI2/SEMOBJ

The App is starting as a standalone application via the index.html. But if we try to launch it on the SAP Fiori Launchpad, the error message appears.

We also tried following component.js where we entered the value of the Additional Information property in the LPD_CUST transaction but we received the same error.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("***.***.***.Component");
    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("***.***.***", {
    createContent : function() {
   // create root view
   this.view = sap.ui.view({
   id : "app",
   viewName : "***.***.***.view.App",
   type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
   viewData : { component : this }
  });
return this.view;
}
});
```

(*** are internal components/paths)

All hints are appreciated.

Regards,

Dominic

Comment: Voting to close since the relevant code is missing to reproduce the issue. And the question author is no longer an active SO user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is linking you to the controller of your application. Please make sure you instantiated the objects correctly. Maybe there is a problem with instantiating an OData Model. Check if you use "new". See syntax below:

https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "new" when instantiating an object, for example on your second option:

```
   this.view = new sap.ui.view({
       id : "app",
       viewName : "***.***.***.view.App",
       type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
       viewData : { component : this }
  });
```

I don't think that's the answer to your problem, but I think it was an error and maybe it can help you somehow.